# Multiple date picker with only current week days enabled

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm looking for a date picker which displays only current week along with multiple date selection by the user.

This [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/as8033qy/3/) enables only the current week, but does not have multiple date selections.

I tried multidate:true, but it didn't work. Is there a way to add? Or is it not possible? So that I'll go ahead I'm changing my plans.

I'm trying since a week but did not succeed.

JavaScript Code :

```
 $(function () { $('.pickWeek').datetimepicker({
    multidate:true,
    locale: 'pt-br', 
    format: "DD/MM/YYYY", 
    sideBySide: true, 
    daysOfWeekDisabled: [0] }); 
    $('.pickWeek').data("DateTimePicker").minDate(moment().startOf('week'));
$('.pickWeek').data("DateTimePicker").maxDate(moment().endOf('week')); });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might need to change the bootstrap datetimepicker plugin to bootstrap datepicker plugin..

```js
$(function () {        
        $('.pickWeek').datepicker({
            locale: 'pt-br',
            format: "dd/mm/yyyy",
            sideBySide: true,
            daysOfWeekDisabled: [0],
            multidate:true,
            startDate:moment().startOf('week').toDate(),
            endDate:moment().endOf('week').toDate()
        });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.13.0/moment.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.8.0/css/bootstrap-datepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.13.0/locale/pt-br.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.8.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>

Mulitple Date Selection
<div class="form-group">
    <div class='input-group date pickWeek'>
        <span class="input-group-addon">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
        </span>
        <input type='text' class="form-control" />
    </div>
</div>
```

I have added both example on jsfiddle which you can test it working [here](http://jsfiddle.net/nimittshah/huqdoa4p/)

Comment: Thank you Nimit. This helped me :)